# React router link with params do not redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I'm on the page that uses param for example: /user/ant, I want to go to /delete, but my link adds to the /user and I'm getting /user/desiredLink

My routes code

```
<Route path="/user/:usr">
    <User />
</Route>

<Route path="/user">
    <User />
</Route>
```

Comment: What's the Link look like? Does it have a leading slash?

Comment: after adding slash to the beginning of the link page is operating correctly